# Pentaho Data Integration: Error connecting to database: using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, pentaho, data-integration

I get this error but I have my mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar inside Pentaho\data-integration\libext\JDBC. It seems the connector is not loaded because it's using the default one. I have tried different versions of jdbc, I've checked MD5, and I don't have other versions of the same driver in the same folder. I'm pretty desperate to make this work, any suggestion is appreciated.

This is the output when I try to write to a database:

```
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : An error occurred intialising this step: 
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Couldn't execute SQL: TRUNCATE TABLE bd_evu.ids_Codigos
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inicializando el paso [Salida Tabla]
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : An error occurred intialising this step: 
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error occured while trying to connect to the database
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Salida Tabla 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inicializando el paso [Salida Tabla 2]
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Zona - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : ¡No se ha podido inicializar el paso [Salida Tabla.0]!
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Zona - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : ¡No se ha podido inicializar el paso [Salida Tabla 2.0]!
2013/05/16 01:00:38 - Entrada Tabla.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure thats not a problem on the server side?  Can you connect to that database with the same credentials/driver and truncate that table manually using SquirrelSQL or some other SQL tool?  also make sure you connect from the same host where you are running PDI, maybe there are some host specific permissions/restrictions in place.